# Exponential random variables, given one smaller

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I can't seem to grasp the following:

Let $X_1 \sim \exp(\lambda_1), X_2 \sim \exp(\lambda_2)$ and independent.

Then $$ \mathbb{E}\left[X_1 | X_1 < X_2\right] = \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} $$

**Why?** **How do I get this result?**

Also, is this somehow related to $ \mathbb{E}\left[\min(X_1,X_2)\right] = \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} $? If so, why are they the same?

I would prefer answers that solve it using identities rather than pdf/CDF.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes, that's a typo. I'll correct it now.

Comment: The two results are clearly related in that one follows from the other: $E(X_1\mid X_1<X_2)$ is the same as $E(\min(X_1,X_2)\mid X_1<X_2)$ and then if the expectation of the minimum is the same no matter whether $X_1<X_2$ or $X_2<X_1$, then this common value must also be the unconditional expectation of the minimum (because $X_1=X_2$ almost never).

Comment: I get the idea but I would love to prove it based on writing out the conditional expectation opposed to disregarding it based on the premise that the condition disappears because it's redundant (same in both cases).

Comment: x @Jean: Well, $\min(X_1,X_2)$ is _defined_ by cases according to whether $X_1<X_2$ or not -- the first thing to do when trying to compute its expectation would be to split into those two cases _anyway_. It's just serendipity that those conditional expectations turn out to be symmetric in $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ (if indeed they are; I have no independent knowledge that your formula is even right).

Comment: Note that the claim about $E(X_1\mid X_1<X_2)$ does _not_ follow from that about $E(\min(X_1,X_2))$ -- only the other way around.

Comment: @HenningMakholm So my last question would be: how did you find the symmetry? Is there a nice identity for that?

Comment: x @Jean: I'm confused here. Are you asking how I noticed that $\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$ is the same as $\frac{1}{\lambda_2+\lambda_1}$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Why is $\mathbb{E}[\min(X_1,X_2)|X_1<X_2]=\mathbb{E}[\min(X_1,X_2)|X_1\geq X_2]$ ?

Comment: x @Jean: Because each of them, according to your first claim, equals $1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Which first claim? I don't get this part. How can we conclude this so quickly?

Comment: x @Jean: It's the very first displayed equation in your question!

Comment: @HenningMakholm But that equation doesn't say that it's the same as the other conditional expectation? ($X_1 \geq X_2$)

Comment: x @Jean: If does, if you interchange 1 and 2.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Mmm ok. Maybe I get a bit confused with the conditioning. But I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using pdf's. I'll use $X,Y$ instead of $X_1,X_2$.
$$
E[X|X<Y]
=\frac{\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty x\cdot\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}\cdot \lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2 y}\,dy\,dx}{P(X<Y)}
$$
We first compute the intergral.
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty x\cdot\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}\cdot \lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2 y}\,dy\,dx
&=\int_0^\infty x\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}(-e^{-\lambda_2y})\big|^\infty_x\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty x\lambda_1e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x}\,dx\\
&=-x\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x}\bigg|^\infty_0+\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\int_0^\infty \lambda_1e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\lambda_1}{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2}
\end{align}
Now we compute $P(X<Y)$.
\begin{align}
P(X<Y)
&=\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}\cdot \lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2 y}\,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \lambda_1e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x}\,dx=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}
\end{align}
Dividing the last two gives that $E[X|X<Y]=\frac1{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$.